# Highlight lines that match a regex in Sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I get SublimeText to highlight lines that match a certain regex?

Answer (score 1):

if you do a `ctrl+f` (`cmd+f` if on mac) you'll see beside the finder text box an icon that has `.*` click that toggle then place in your regex, you're matches with be outlined.

Comment: Sorry, I must clarify, I meant, how do I go about writing a syntax highlighter for a custom DSL.